# How can I get pre-canned scripts for perf script?

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, kernel, scripts

`man 1 perf-script` says that there are pre-canned scripts available with `perf script -l`, but when I invoke the command it outputs

```
open(/usr/libexec/perf-core/scripts) failed.
Check "PERF_EXEC_PATH" env to set scripts dir.
```

Perf itself runs flawlessly and collects the needed data. I have `linux-tools-5.13.0-35-generic` installed which matches my kernel.

What package should I install or should I rebuild the `perf` package myself? Can I just copy the scripts from somewhere and modify environment variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=scripts%2Fpython%2Fflamegraph.py doesn't list any, so the it seems you have to copy those from the linux kernel tools, in your case from  https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/acme/linux.git/tree/tools/perf/scripts?h=perf-tools-fixes-for-v5.13-2021-06-19

Note that the usefulness depends on the question if your distributed perf has python and/or perl support. If this isn't available then you'd need to build perf yourself, using:

```sh
PERF_VER="perf-tools-fixes-for-v6.1-1-2023-01-06"
KERNEL_REPO="git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/acme/linux.git"

sudo apt install -y bison flex libelf-dev libnewt-dev libdw-dev libaudit-dev libiberty-dev libunwind-dev \
          libcap-dev libzstd-dev liblzma-dev libnuma-dev libssl-dev systemtap-sdt-dev libbabeltrace-ctf-dev \
          libperl-dev libtraceevent-dev \
          binutils-dev gcc-multilib \
          python3-dev \
          libgtk2.0-dev
      #   asciidoc                 optional, only for manpages, depdencies are huge

git clone --depth 1 --filter=blob:none --sparse $KERNEL_REPO
cd linux
git sparse-checkout set tools scripts arch
git fetch --depth 1 origin $PERF_VER
export PERF_EXEC_PATH=$PWD/tools/perf
nice make -C $PERF_EXEC_PATH -j $(nproc) PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
```

Which you then may use with

```sh
# variable set above
$PERF_EXEC_PATH/perf script -l
```